# why CreateObjectFromJSON fails at the first run on Realm?

Tags: android, database, realm

again it's me with another question on Realm so I had a small problem with **CreateObjectFromJSON**   which is    `Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Primary key constraint broken. Value already exists:0` 
even I saw [in Github](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/858) thats was a bug and it's corrected but I found the same error in the last version 0.80 of Realm Android.
But when I use **CreateOrUpdateObjectFromJson** it works correctly
What is the solution ? I

Comment: Note that if you JSON doesn't contain a field, it will be assigned a default value, which is 0 for integers. So most likely some of your JSON doesn't have the field you set as a primary key? How does your JSON look like?

Comment: .....`{
application: {
parameters: {
id: 999,
account_id: 41,
languages: [
"fr",
"en"
],
url: "",
title: "Le Cep",
client: "Hôtel Le Cep",
creation_date: 1381218600,
modification_date: 1418722140,
foreground_color: "613D53",
background_color: "FFFFFF",
title_font: "Palatino-Bold",
body_font: "Avenir-Book",
title_font_android: "Droid",
body_font_android: "Droid",
title_color: "5E314C",
body_color: "0",
tabs_background_color: "5E314C",
side_tabs_background_color: "5E314C",`

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a small sample project?

Comment: OK i'll try it and I'll come back soon

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, for no apparent reason because my JSON had the primary key specified as a crazy-large number which I knew my database didn't contain. Then I realized, I had just had a bug while it was converting the JSON to the Realm database, and maybe there was a partially-copied JSON file in there? So I thought, there must be an incomplete duplicate from the time I had the bug. I just uninstalled the app, reinstalled, restarted and it worked. So maybe that happened here with your code.